# Why is a constructor run three times when breakpoints are set?

Tags: c#, class, constructor

Try to compile this code. Why does ctor work 3 times ?
Add breakpoint before output and debug it.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(new A().a);
}

class A
{
    public int a;
    public A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `ctor work 3 times ?` what does it mean? What output you are getting and what output you are expecting?

Comment: Try to compile it and you will see

Comment: I get `37489757` and `0` as output.

Comment: Are we seeing the whole program here? is there something else?

Comment: Try to add breakpoint before output and debug it, you will see

Comment: #1) The `Writeline` in `Main` #2) the  A() ctor, #3) the .a print. (this is the one that prints 0).  The ctor doesnt run 3 times, but you do have 2 print statements, 1 of which prints 2 things

Comment: See the edit in my answer -- OP is right, setting breakpoints in a certain way does cause triplicate prints.

Comment: @AKX I tried to reproduce it as in your answer, but with no luck. What version of VS do you use?

Comment: This is a freshly installed VS2017 Community 15.7.6.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The constructor works exactly once for me without breakpoints.
[image]

However, with breakpoints added as illustrated, there are indeed what seem to be three calls to `A()`.

[image]

Comment: Try to add breakpoint before output and debug it, you will se what i'm talking about

Answer (score 5):

This is a side effect of a debugging setting in Visual Studio.  Go to Tools->Options, then Debugging->General. Un-check "Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls".  Then your behavior with and without breakpoints will be consistent.

Alternatively, you can just change the line in your main method to this:

```
Console.WriteLine((new A()).a);
```